# Tables for content versioning getting out of sync

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have implemented content versioning with two tables. I understand that this is maybe not the optimal implementation, but it's what I've got to work with.

One is Contents, which has an int Id and other fields like Title, HtmlContent, etc.

The other is ContentVersions. It has a foreign key to Content Id and also a Version field which represents the content revision and also an IsCurrent flag which represents which version is the current once (of which a copy exists in the Contents table). It also has the other fields like Title, HtmlContent, etc.

When a user updates content, the system is supposed to create a new ContentVersion and update the corresponding Content. I am using Entity Framework and it looks kinda like this:

```
        // ASP.NET MVC Action
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Save(ContentVersion contentVersion)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    var versions = contentVersionRepository.GetById(contentVersion.Id)
                            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Version)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (versions == null)
                        contentVersion.Version = 1;
                    else
                        contentVersion.Version = versions.Version + 1;
                    contentVersion.IsCurrent = false;
                    contentVersion.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                    contentVersionRepository.Save(contentVersion);
                    contentVersionRepository.UpdateCurrent(contentVersion);
                    scope.Complete();

                    return Json(new { status = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { status = "fail" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }

    // EF repository
    public class ContentVersionRepository {
        private readonly MyEfContext context;
        private readonly DbSet<ContentVersion> dbset;

        public MyEfContext DataContext {
            get { return context; }
        }

        public IList<ContentVersion> GetById(int id)
        {
            return context
                .Database.SqlQuery<ContentVersion>(string.Format(@"select * From ContentVersions c Where c.Id = {0}", id))
                .OrderBy(v=>v.Version)
                .ToList();
        }

        public int Save(ContentVersion version)
        {
            Entities.Add(version);
            return context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public int UpdateCurrent(ContentVersion version)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("Execute SP_UPDATE_CURRENT {0},{1};", version.Id, version.Version));
            return 0;
        }

        public DbSet Entities {
            get { return dbset; }
        }

        public ContentVersionRepository(MyEfContext context) {
            this.context = context;
            dbset = context.ContentVersions;
        }
    }
}
```

The SP_UPDATE_CURRENT sproc looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UPDATE_CURRENT](@Id INT, @Version INT)
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE ContentVersions SET IsCurrent = CASE WHEN [Version] = @Version THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE Id = @Id;
    UPDATE Contents SET
        Title = cv.Title,
        HtmlContent = cv.HtmlContent,
        Summary = cv.Summary
    FROM Contents c
    INNER JOIN ContentVersions cv ON c.Id = cv.Id
    WHERE cv.Id = @Id AND cv.IsCurrent = 1
END;

GO
```

However, users are reporting that every once in a while, when saving new versions, the Content is out of sync. That is: the Content table is not updated correctly. The new ContentVersion record is there, but its IsCurrent is false (0). This doesn't always happen, just occasionally.

My thought was that it was double clicking causing some sort of race condition, but I put some JS in place to keep users from double clicking, and I also added the TransactionScope, just in case. Still, the issue persists.

I've looked at this code over and over and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `contentVersionRepository`?

Comment: Just normal constructor injection

Answer (score 1):

You don't have duplicate verison numbers, right? Make a unique index on (contentid, version) to make sure.

Make the transaction serializable which by definition excludes *all* concurrency issues.

Use SQL Profiler with transaction tracing to make sure that all database calls as part of Save happen inside a single session and a single transaction. Sometimes, calls can "slip out" and this is hard to tell from the source code.

Btw, your mix of EF and raw SQL is kind of strange and error prone. If the object model that EF maintains becomes out of sync with respect to the database behavior becomes undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the transaction serializable"?

Comment: Use `IsolationLevel.Serializable`. The database will ensure that the transaction behaves as if it was the only transaction in the system. This excludes all concurrency bugs.

Comment: Like so?:             `var tso = new TransactionOptions();
            tso.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tso))`

Comment: Yes. Now make sure this "took" by using SQL Profiler. You never know for sure with TransactionScope until you've tested it.